# Use Python To Sum A Series

Tags: python

So I have the code

```
def formula(n):
    while(n < 11):
        answera = 15/(-4)** n
        print(answera)
        n = n + 1

formula(1)
```

How can I add the outputs in condescending order?

For example,

```
first_output = (the output of n = 1)

second_output = (the output of n = 1) + (the output of n = 2)

third_output =  (the output of n = 1) + (the output of n = 2) + (the output of n = 3)
```

and so on..

Comment: nth output = the output when n + (n-1)th output

Comment: Do you care about the intermediate output?  That is, do you care if you see what `formula(1)` and `formula(2)` look like?  And to be clear:  you want to take `formula` and apply it to a list of inputs like 1, 2, 3..., right?

Comment: Your function is not clear. For `n=1`, should the result be the sum of 10 times `15/(-4)** n` for 10 different `n` values? or  `formula(n)` should just return `15/(-4)** n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to define the variable `answera` outside the while loop, so that its shope should exists outside the loop , so that when you return the value the fully updated value can be returned. Something like this.

```
def formula(n):
    answera = 0
    while(n < 11):
        answera += 15/(-4)** n
        print(answera)
        n = n + 1
    print(answera)

formula(1)
```

Now it should give you the right result.

Answer (score 1):

```
def formula(n):
    while(n < 11):
        answera  += 15/(-4)** n
        print(answera)
        n = n + 1
```

The idea is that you will need to accumlate the value of `15/(-4)**n` in one of the variables.. (here the answera) and keep printing it out.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's some ambiguity in your question; do you want the sum of 'answera', or the sum of 'formula'?

If 'answera', then you can just replace "print" with "yield" and call "sum":

```
def formula(n):
    while(n < 11):
        answera  += 15/(-4)** n
        yield answera
        n = n + 1

sum(formula(2))
```

This makes 'formula' a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), and "sum" will iterate that generator until it's exhausted.

If you want the sum of multiple 'formula' calls, then follow the KISS principle, and wrap your function with another function:

```
# assuming that 'formula' is a generator like above

def mega_formula(iterations):
    total = []
    for i in range(1, iterations + 1): # b/c range indexs from zero
        total.append(sum(formula(i))
    return sum(total)
```